# Getting claims using MSAL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I am using `Microsoft.Identity.Claim` library to conenct to azure and authenticate user.
My first idea was to use `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` method but that requires few days until network administrator people investigate how to enable single sign-in option and change that user are now "federated" and not "managed. So I now switched to `AcquireTokenInteractive` method because chances are that ure will be logged in, so he will just need to choose account from automatically opened browser and that's it. No big deal.

And this works:

```
   string clientId = "xxx";
            var tenantId = "yyy";
              string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All"};

        AuthenticationResult result;

        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                 .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                                                 .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId).Build();
        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                      .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException) //see all possibl exceptions!
        {
```

**However**, I don't receive claims inside token.
My idea is to send this token to server, then validate it, and if sucessfull create user in database and then use my own authenication mechanism I use for other users (that are not part of domain, completely separate user).
But I don't want all users from domain have access to this app.
So I would like to get claims, roles...

How to get claims, using this or any other lib given user email, or some other unique data?

Comment: Hi, may I know which api do you want to request after you get access token ? request a web application api protected by AD or request graph api. It seems you added microsoft graph permissions(`"User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All"`) into `scopes`

Comment: I want to request only one anonymouse non protected method to login user using "mine" existing authentication method? Why, because I already have it and it requires user in database. So, my idea was to insert user in database , if it has good AD roles and generated jwt token from that user I alredy have infrastructure code for

Comment: I'm not so clear about your description. Per my understanding, your requirement is check the claim `roles` in access token but you can't find the claim `roles`, right ?

Comment: Yes. I would like to get roles from that API. I will then know if user has rights to access my application

Comment: If you can't find claim `roles` in access token, it may be caused by you added microsoft graph permissions(`"User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All"`) into `scopes`.

Comment: And what permission I should add?

Comment: May I know if you have followed the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225766/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-vlado-pandzic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I summarize all of the steps you may need to follow:

**1.** You need to register a app in azure ad for your service app, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-dotnet-native-aspnet#register-your-web-api)

**2.** Then you need to register another app in ad as the client app, you can follow the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-dotnet-native-aspnet#register-the-todolistclient-client-app)

**3.** After that, you need to do the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) which I already provided in comments. Do it in the service app but not client app.

**4.** Then you can get the access token with your code and check the claim `roles`. Please note, do not add microsoft graph permissions into `scopes` in your code. You need to add `api://<the client id of the registered app for service app>/.default` into `scopes`.

**5.** Now you can find the claim `roles` in your access token.
[image]